# Translating wikitext (Wiktionary style) into HTML on the client side

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, wikitext, wiktionary

I'm trying to parse [Wiktionary Wikitext](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aWikitext_style) on the client side (with JavaScript). I found [Wiky.js](http://goessner.net/articles/wiky/), but it has problems with some markups like {{}}, + etc. Do you know any JavaScript library which may help me with that? I found, that [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) may [translate wikitext](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse) into HTML. but I get data from API using the [query action](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Exporting_pages), so it would be dummy to request server twice. Maybe there is some way to get HTML instead of Wikitext using the query action? I also found [render action](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#View_and_render), but it sends me the entire page, not only an article.

//edit

Here is part of sample Wikitext:

```
=====Translations===== {{trans-top|on fingers and toes}} * [[Afrikaans]]: [[nael]] * Albanian: [[thua]] {{f}} * Arabic: {{Arab|[[ظفر]]}} (ẓufr) * Armenian: {{t-|hy|եղունգ|tr=eġung}} *: Old Armenian: {{tø|xcl|եղունգն|tr=ełungn|sc=Armn|xs=Old Armenian}} * [[Azeri]]: {{t+|az|dırnaq|xs=Azeri}} * Bosnian: {{t-|bs|nokat|m}} * [[Breton]]: [[ivin]] {{m}}, ivinoù {{p}} * [[Campidanese Sardinian]]: [[unga]] {{f}} * [[Catalan]]: [[ungla]] {{f}} * Chinese: {{zh-zh-p|指甲|zhǐjia}} * Croatian: {{t+|hr|nokat|m|alt=nȍkat}} * Czech: {{t+|cs|nehet|m}} * Danish: {{t+|da|negl}} * Dutch: {{t+|nl|nagel|m}} * [[Erzya]]: [[кенже]] (kenzhe) * Esperanto: {{t-|eo|ungo|xs=Esperanto}} * Estonian: [[küüs]] * Finnish: {{t+|fi|kynsi}} * French: {{t+|fr|ongle|m}} * [[Galician]]: [[unlla]] {{f}}, [[uña]] {{f}} * Georgian: {{t-|ka|ფრჩხილი|tr=p'rč'xili|sc=Geor|xs=Georgian}} * German: {{t+|de|Nagel|m}} * Greek: *: Anciemt: {{tø|grc|ὄνυξ|m|tr=onyx|xs=Ancient Greek}} *: Modern: {{t+|el|νύχι|n|tr=nýchi}} * [[Gujarati]]: [[નખ]] (nakh) {{m}} * Hindi: {{t-|hi|नाख़ुन|m|tr=nāḵẖun|xs=Hindi}}
```

and Wiky.toHtml() output:

```
<h4>Translations</h4>
<p u"="" style="{trans-top</p></td>?(c_u) <li class=">Arabic: {{t-</p>
</li>
arصرعm?(c_u)
<li class="u">Bengali;"&gt;}, {{t-bspadavica?(c_u) </li>
<li class="u">Chinese: *: Mandarin: {{t</li>
cmn癲癇sc=Hani}}, {{tcmn癫痫tr=diānxiánsc=Hani}}, {{tcmn癲癇癥sc=Hani}}, {{tcmn癫痫症tr=diānxiánzhèng?(c_u)
<li class="u">Croatian: {{t-</li>
hrepilepsijafalt=epilèpsija}}, {{t-hrpadavicaf?(c_u)
<li class="u">Czech: {{t-</li>
csepilepsie?(c_u)
<li class="u">Estonian: {{t+</li>
etepilepsia}}, {{t+et?(c_u)
<li class="u">Finnish: {{t+</li>
fi?(c_u)
<li class="u">French: {{t+</li>
frépilepsie?(c_u)
<li class="u">German: {{t+</li>
deEpilepsief}}, {{t-deFallsucht?(c_u)
<li class="u">Greek: {{t+</li>
elεπιληψία?(c_u)
<li class="u">Hindi: {{t-</li>
hiअपस्मारtr=apasmārxs=Hindi}}, {{thiमिर्गीtr=mirgī?(c_u)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wikitext has very complicated edge cases, you cannot expect a javascript library to reliably parse it (though it should be possible to do a much better job than Wiky does). The best is to use action=render, then strip the relevant part from the response (I'm not sure what you mean by entire page vs. article).

Comment: I think the most problematic thing are templates, which are different for every mediawiki based site. Render gives me entire site, with menu, search form etc. I have to extract some data from wikitext into html list and I think (at this moment) the easiest way is to use regular expressions. But anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: @ciembor: Render should only include the content of the article, no search bar or menu (see e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Elephant&action=render)). Maybe you are using a mistyped URL?